# Establishing the right relationship between two classes

Tags: java

For my program I have a `Server` class and a `Protocols` class.

When my Server receives a message from the Client I want the Server to send the message to the Protocols. The Protocols then figure out what needs to be done with the message and invokes the proper methods. Now, the methods that need to be invoked are inside the Server.

So essentially, the Server needs to have access to the Protocols and the Protocols needs to have access to the Server.

What is the best way to establish such a relationship? How would I do it?
I don't want a circular reference, but is there another way?

Comment: elaborate what are those methods in server doing?

Answer (score 1):

What about following the Servlet model of request/response objects?

Every time you receive a message, you package it up in a request object, and you create a response object, and send it to you protocol handler (acting as a kind of servlet).

Your handler, deals with the request, and whatever it needs to pass back, it puts it in the response object, which is ultimately used by the server to send the actual response to the client. If the server needs to take any decisions, it can do it based on the information already provided in the response object after the request has been attended by your protocol handler.

You may later add similar concepts to those of the servlet model, like filters or event handlers to deal with similar requirements.